# How to save data to sales_shipment_grid table while saving it to sales_shipment table in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, grid

After creating shipment I'm saving additional data to it and need to display this data in shipment grid.

I've added column named `'some_data'` in `sales_shipment` and `sales_shipment_grid` tables in database. Also added UI components to display this column in shipment_grid:

```
sales_order_shipment_grid.xml

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_shipment_columns">
        <column name="some_data">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Some Data</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Also added configuration in MyNamespace/MyModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="ShipmentGridAggregator" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="some_data" xsi:type="string">sales_shipment.some_data</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Value successfully saves to `sales_shipment` table but not to `sales_shipment_grid` table, therefore column in admin shipment grid remains empty.

**How can I populate this custom column with data from `sales_shipment` table column?**

Maybe there are other approaches? 
All examples I've found were for `sales_order_grid` and they does not work for `sales_shipment_grid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's working. The only thing needed changes was to add above di configuration to MyNamespace/MyModule/etc/di.xml (not MyNamespace/MyModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml).